# Setting PostgresSQL for my VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, vps

I am about to deploy my app to a vps for the first time, and running into some issues while configuring my DB.

After running the following commands...

```
# PostgreSQL
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install postgresql libpq-dev
```

everything seemed to work fine until

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I was supposed to login to psql, but the command did not do anything (didn't return anything). I tried

```
su postgres
```

instead, and it got me to *postgres@myaccount:/root$*

and then I tried

```
sudo postgres psql
```

and it asked me for the password, but the *root password* did not work for this.

What's the right way of logging into postgres in this case, and how do I set up my database?

**UPDATE:** I tried the following,

```
root@max:~# su postgres
postgres@max:/root$ psql
bash: /usr/bin/psql: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think psql is supposed to run as postgres user . You should not type 'sudo' .

```
root@myaccount:/root$ su postgres
postgres@myaccount:/root$ psql
```

Comment: when I do psql create user, it gives me usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: permission denied

Comment: When you issue 'psql' command as a postgres user , it takes you to command prompt . There you should type : create user your_user with password 'password'; (notice the semicolon at the end of the sql command). In case the user is created successfully , you should see something like CREATE ROLE.

Comment: check my update please

Comment: As 'postgres' , what does $ echo $PATH shows ? Is your perl package installed ? (on debian : apt-cache policy perl)

Comment: Installing perl solved the problem!

Comment: I'm happy for you . Good luck with the app.